# How do I force a javascript event listener to terminate the function it is in?

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

So I've been working on a program for my final for an ap class and I'm using javascript and for some bizarre reason the eventlistener isn't working at all. I've been staring at this for actual hours now and trying to get it to stop terminate the function it is in so that it can go back up to the function that called it originally. And I'm not having any luck, I have like 2 days to figure this out someone please help

This is supposed to be the code that takes the id and figures out which thing the player is indicating but it's refusing to terminate this function. There are 7 buttons attached to the parent and it works as a one time click currently but refuses to leave after it's clicked. Please someone help...

```js
function playerTurn(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  var roll = showRoll();
  
  if(roll == 0){
   return;
  }
  else if(roll > 0){
   var id = "";
   const parent = document.querySelector('#stoneSelects');
   parent.addEventListener('click', function oneTimeClick(event){
    //console.log(event.target.id);
    id = event.target.id;
    parent.removeEventListener(event.type, oneTimeClick);
    if(id != ""){
     console.log("User picked: "+id);
     return;
    }
  });
   
  }
 }, 500);
}
```

Comment: share html as well.

Comment: @as.if.i.code will do, thanks

Comment: don't rebind to the event in another event - your timer.

Comment: @DanielA.White I removed the timer completely and it didn't change anything. The function keeps refusing the terminate

Comment: There's a one time event listener now: `EventTarget.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Do something cool

}, {once : true});`

Comment: @user120242 sadly I've already tried that, and that doesn't work either

Comment: put a console.log and/or a breakpoint where you attach the listener to make sure you aren't attaching it more than once

Comment: actually explain what you mean by terminate your function.  what do you mean by that?  post working runnable code that shows the problem, and your intended input and desired output